# h:selectOneListBox Validation Error: Value is not Valid

Tags: validation, jsf, equals, selectonelistbox

I am getting a Validation Error: Value is not valid error. I have identified the problem to be the equals method. The object selected gets passed correctly as an argument, but for some reason, the entity that is compared with is wrong.

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
          <h:selectOneListbox id="${cc.attrs.id}_test" converter="#{cc.attrs.converter}" 
                              size="#{cc.attrs.selector.selectedList.size()+1}" style="height: 150px"
                              value="#{cc.attrs.selector.removeItem}" styleClass="form-control">
            <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.selector.selectedList}" var="test" 
                           itemValue="#{test}"
                           itemLabel="#{test.displayName}" />
            <f:ajax event="change" render="${cc.attrs.id}_jts_panel ${cc.attrs.id}_legend" />
          </h:selectOneListbox>
</div>
```

Here is the equals method:

```
@Override
  public boolean equals(Object object)
  {
    if (!(object instanceof ObjectTest))
    {
      return false;
    }

    ObjectTest other = (ObjectTest) object;

    if (this.attribute1 == null || this.attribute2 == null) {
      return false;
    } 

    if (other.attribute1 == null || other.attribute2 == null) {
      return false;
    }

    if ((this.attribute1.getName() == null && other.attribute1.getName() != null) || (this.attribute1.getName() != null && !this.attribute1.getName().equals(other.attribute1.getName())))
    {
      return false;
    }
    if ((this.attribute2.getName() == null && other.attribute2.getName() != null) || (this.attribute2.getName() != null && !this.attribute2.getName().equals(other.attribute2.getName())))
    {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Now for some reason, this.attribute1.getName() is different than other.attribute1.getName(). The object passed into the equals method is the correct one, but the entity itself is a different one than the object passed. How is the value of this.attribute being picked up since this is an entity class where the equals method is at? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not much to understand your problem, my guess is that you converter is causing your problem: `converter="#{cc.attrs.converter}"` what does this evaluates to?

Comment: You are correct Jorge. Can you add your reply as an answer below so I can accept it as the correct one please? And thank you.

Comment: Done it. Not much to explain just added the comment as an answer like you asked. Glad that it helped you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the comment I added solved your problem and you ask to add it, here it is:

The problem was caused by the converter you are using:

```
converter="#{cc.attrs.converter}"
```